# Bias nodes in Dlib MLP?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, dlib

I create a multi-layer perceptron network in Dlib:

```
mlp::kernel_1a_c net(2,5);
```

This has 2 nodes on the input layer, and 5 nodes in the first hidden layer. Does this network already include bias nodes? Or must I add them myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has bias nodes already.

However, I should point out that the dlib::mlp class is super old and awful. I'm saying this as the author of dlib. You would fare much better off using one of the more modern machine learning tools in dlib, like an SVM. Or if you really want to use some kind of deep learning tool use the [modern deep learning API](http://blog.dlib.net/2016/06/a-clean-c11-deep-learning-api.html) in dlib.

Comment: Thanks. I actually just want to provide a minimal xor training implementation to support my students' learning. They have been shown the MLP only as a first step. I am new to Dlib though, and I like what I see.

Comment: Ok. In that case carry on :)